# Finding the Number of pending requests allowed on a Webpage in chrome?

Tags: http, google-chrome

When a HTTP request is not completed/cannot be completed in chrome, it says status pending.

I am trying to dynamically modifying the contents of my webpage with ajax requests. I have a couple of ajax requests based on different events on my page. If a few HTTP requests cannot be completed/or stop prematurely when that event ends, I get status pending for these HTTP requests.

But, the problem is whatever HTTP requests are made on this webpage after a couple of these HTTP pending requests, they too become pending requests without being actually requested by the chrome browser. I think they are added on to the queue. This happens on after there are a definitive number of pending requests - 2 for my browser.

I am not sure how to disable this queue or increase the number of allowable HTTP pending requests and allow other HTTP requests to flow through. If anyone can give me an idea of how this works and how to change this setting .. it would be great.

Comment: I just recently ran into the 'pending' issue in Chrome.  I tried disabling all extensions, but no luck.  The issue for me however, just suddenly started happening.  I didn't add new ajax requests to my project, so I'm not sure why this would be happening.  I don't have the issue in other browsers, so I might try reinstalling chrome.